# Populate multi-dimension array through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Update**

I get an error `syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'` on the line below:

```
<?php
$data['datasets'] = [{
                        label: 'Quotation',
                        backgroundColor: '#96ccf1',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    },{
                        label: 'Purchase Order',
                        backgroundColor: '#96ccf1',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    },{
                        label: 'Invoice',
                        backgroundColor: '#96ccf1',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    }];
?>
```

I have the original js code which I want to change into dynamic data retrieval. I'm able to change the `labels` part but unable to change the `datasets` part.

Given the original data looks like (refer below), how to amend my PHP code so that when passed through ajax it can successfully display the correct data? Am I missing some quotes here and there??

Thank you.

**Original JS code (static)**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'action':'RetrieveData'},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        if(data.status=='success'){
            var barChartData = {
                labels: ["01-Oct-2017","07-Oct-2017","14-Oct-2017","21-Oct-2017","28-Oct-2017"],
                datasets: [{
                            label: 'Quotation',
                            backgroundColor: '#96ccf1',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            data: [
                                100,500,5000,800,500
                            ]
                        }, {
                            label: 'Purchase Order',
                            backgroundColor: '#FAD84E',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            data: [
                                100,500,2500,800,500
                            ]
                        }, {
                            label: 'Invoice',
                            backgroundColor: '#9FFA4E',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            data: [
                                100,500,2000,800,0
                            ]
                        }]
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: data.title_text
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('Error occurred');
    }
});
```

**Amended JS code (dynamic)**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'action':'RetrieveData'},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        if(data.status=='success'){
            var barChartData = {
                labels: data.labels, // <-- This is correct
                datasets: data.datasets // <-- I need help on this part
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: data.title_text
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('Error occurred');
    }
});
```

PHP code

```
$data['labels'] = ["01-Oct-2017","07-Oct-2017","14-Oct-2017","21-Oct-2017","28-Oct-2017"];
$data['datasets'] = [{
                        label: 'Quotation',
                        backgroundColor: '#96ccf1',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    },{
                        label: 'Purchase Order',
                        backgroundColor: '#96ccf1',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    },{
                        label: 'Invoice',
                        backgroundColor: '#96ccf1',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    }];

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unable" ? Do you have an error in the console ?

Comment: Hi, sorry yes please refer to the updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an object like `{label: 'some name'}` you can use a class or an associative array `['label' => 'some name']`. PHP isn't be able to create one of the previous mentioned elements out of an `{}`.

```
$data['labels'] = ["01-Oct-2017","07-Oct-2017","14-Oct-2017","21-Oct-2017","28-Oct-2017"];
$data['datasets'] = [[
                        'label' => 'Quotation',
                        'backgroundColor' => '#96ccf1',
                        'borderWidth' => 1,
                        'data' => [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    ],[
                        'label' => 'Purchase Order',
                        'backgroundColor' => '#96ccf1',
                        'borderWidth' => 1,
                        'data' => [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    ],[
                        'label' => 'Invoice',
                        'backgroundColor' => '#96ccf1',
                        'borderWidth' => 1,
                        'data' => [
                            100,500,5000,800,500
                        ]
                    ]];

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: PHP understands objects, it just has a different notation

Comment: Your're absolutely right I've chosen the wrong wording and will update my answer.

Comment: So basically JS object use `{'key':'value'}` while PHP object use `['key'=>'value']` is it?